# Getting large data from MySQL database in lumps (like PhpStorm does it)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpstorm

In my database, I have huge tables with a couple of billions of results and the problems are that my PHP code is not capable of getting it right. I'm waiting for hours of results and almost always get an error like 'served moved away' or 'maximum limit of passing data is xx'.

Tables have indexed columns. Queries are simplified to the minimum. I have tried some test in PHP but all of them failed.

```
// approach #1 with PHP
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=".$data["host"].";dbname=".$data["dbname"].";charset=utf8", $data["username"], $data["pass"]);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = "SELECT id FROM huge_table bt INNER JOIN even_bigger_table ebt ON bt.id = ebt.id WHERE bt.column = 'data1' AND ebt.column2 = 'data2'";

// ends up with error with no results
$pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll();

// approach #2 with PHP
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=".$data["host"].";dbname=".$data["dbname"].";charset=utf8", $data["username"], $data["pass"]);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$resultsCounted = 5000000;
$offset = 0;

for($i = 0; $offset < $resultsCounted; $i += 500) {
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM huge_table bt INNER JOIN even_bigger_table ebt ON bt.id = ebt.id WHERE bt.column = 'data1' AND ebt.column2 = 'data2' LIMIT ".$offset.", 500";

    // ends up with error with no results
    $result = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll();

    // do some stuff with results
    do_stuff($result);

    $offset += $i;
}
```

Strangely this SQL works in PhpStorm database console when selecting "Execute to file" function:

```
SELECT id FROM huge_table bt INNER JOIN even_bigger_table ebt ON bt.id = ebt.id WHERE bt.column = 'data1' AND ebt.column2 = 'data2'
```

I can see how PhpStorm saves 100 by 100 results into the file until all are saved.

I need to find a way how can I recreate PhpStorm database data saving that with PHP or find another way how to properly manage results saving.

Comment: The word you're looking for is `pagination` and can be done with the offset/limit keywords.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

Comment: look  at  approach #2 with PHP it does not work for me

Comment: You may also use `cursors` to reduce memory usage. PhpStorm must be using pagination for sure (`LIMIT` for MySQL)

Comment: pagination with large offsets will not scale.. `LIMIT 1000000, 1000` MySQL would need to fetch `1001000` records to throw away `1000000` again and most likely would need to create a (disk) temporary table to execute.

Comment: Also using `LIMIT` without using `ORDER BY` is pretty much **meaningless**.. SQL standard defined that SQL tables/resultsets are **orderless** .. Your results are [nondeterministic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_algorithm) (random) now.. To get it deterministic (fixed) you would need to add a column in the ORDER BY which is a `PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE key` or you know the column have unique values.

Comment: What exactly are you doing with the results?  Are you able to [fetch()](https://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) one row at a time and process it instead of the entire result-set in one go?

Comment: In addition to what Raymond Nijland said -- if you order by some ID ... then for every next chunk you can add extra `WHERE` condition so it will work with records that past that ID (e.g. `AND WHERE id > :last_id` if sorted by ID in ASC order).

Comment: @patrickQ I'm fixing them and passing into a file.

thank you guys for the answers, will try your recommendations and inform you with results

Answer (score 0):

`LIMIT hugenumber smallnumber` generally works poorly: it's a notorious performance antipattern.  MySQL has to work hard to skip over a `hugenumber` of records before returning a `smallnumber`. Then it has to do it all again, and again...

Instead process your rows one at a time. 
Most queries in php are *buffered*.  That is, `fetchAll()` and its equivalents slurp up everything in the query resultset in one big gulp.

That works badly for queries with vast resultsets, partly because most php implementations have RAM limits.

Use an [unbuffered query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php) for this. Process the rows you need one at a time, then discard them. That way your resultset will flow through your php program in a continuous stream. (I did not debug this example).

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false);

$sql = "SELECT id FROM huge_table bt INNER JOIN even_bigger_table ebt ON bt.id = ebt.id WHERE bt.column = 'data1' AND ebt.column2 = 'data2'";
$unbuff = $pdo->query($sql);
if ($unbuff) {
   while ($row = $unbuff->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
       echo $row['whatever']; /* handle the row */
   }
}
```